# Why is object property marked as uncovered by flow?

Tags: flowtype

Checking the flow coverage of the following:

```
// @flow
import type { Map } from 'immutable';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const formOptions: {
  foo: Map<string, *>,
} = {
  foo: fromJS({
    some: 'value',
  }),
};
```

It reports the `fromJS`part as uncovered:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/flow coverage --json --pretty foo.js
{
  "expressions":{
    "covered_count":5,
    "uncovered_count":1,
    "uncovered_locs":[
      {
        "source":"/Users/jacob/Code/nova/manage-web/app/containers/ResendVerification/foo.js",
        "type":"SourceFile",
        "start":{"line":8,"column":8,"offset":141},
        "end":{"line":10,"column":4,"offset":173}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How should that be annotated to make sure it's fully covered?

Comment: Recommend noting in the title that this is specific to the `immutable` library

Answer (score 1):

It's because `fromJS` returns `any`.

If a "properly typed" Map is constructed it's covered:

```
// @flow
// import type { Map } from 'immutable';
import { Map } from 'immutable';

const formOptions: {
  foo: Map<string, *>,
} = {
  foo: Map({
    some: 'value',
  }),
};
```